# Laravel 5.2: Authenticate Controller action Role wise using Entrust

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing, entrust

New in laravel. I have done this in Yii And it is pretty much easy. :)

Laravel Version: 5.2
Entrust Version: dev-laravel-5

Let me explain my requirement.
I have two role manager and ceo. and they have following permissions.

```
In PostController:
    1.Role: Manager
      Action: View
    2.Role : CEO
      Action: create,edit,delete
```

i created role with above permissions.

Now let's see what i have done. i create two middleware RoleCheck to check role and PermissionCheck to check permission

RoleCheck.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

    class RoleCheck
    {
      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            // Get the required roles from the route
            $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());

            // Check if a role is required for the route, and
            // if so, ensure that the user has that role.
            if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
            {
                        return $next($request);
            }
                    return response()->view('errors.401');
        }

        public function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
        {
            $actions = $route->getAction();
            return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
        }
    }
```

PermissionCheck.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class PermissionCheck
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission= null)
    {   
        //exit;
        if (\Auth::user()->can($permission)) {

            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response()->view('errors.401');
        }

    }
}
```

now i added this middleware to Kernel.php in routeMiddleware array

```
'role' => Middleware\RoleCheck::class,
'permission' => Middleware\PermissionCheck::class
```

now Authenticate role i have added

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role']], function () {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
});
```

this works perfect. but i can't authenticate user their permission given in role.

In PostController.php

```
function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('permission:can_view',['only'=>'show']);
        $this->middleware('permission:can_create_post',['only'=>'create','store']);
        $this->middleware('permission:can_update_post',['only'=>'edit','update']);
        $this->middleware('permission:can_delete_post',['only'=>'destroy']);
    }
```

and route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web','permission'], function () { 
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');            
});
```

This works perfect. But this authentication is based on permission. But now i want to Authenticate based on given role. so try to change route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','role'],'roles'=>['Manager','CEO']], function () { 
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');            
});
```

and removed __construct() function. But here I face problem. User with `Role` can access all actions which are not assigned to him. and User with `Manager` can access all actions which are not assigned to him also.

How to do that?How can authenticate assigned permission in role. i am now totally confused between middleware and authentication. Any help please.